# DOMPDF background image looks sharp sometimes

Tags: php, dompdf

Im using DOMPDF to create a certificate so people can print it. Problem is that the background image sometimes looks sharp. And thats the thing sometimes looks nice , sometimes not and im not sure why.

My pdf html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
<style>
    @page {
     margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:841px;
        height:545px;
        font-family:Verdana;
            }
    #lol{
        width:841px;
        height:545px;
        background:url(30-Day-Goals-Certificate.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    position:relative;
    }
    .eating{
        position: absolute;
        top: 355px;
        left: 425px;
        color: #02436d;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family:"proxima";
    }
    .exercise{
        position: absolute;
        top: 387px;
        left: 455px;
        color: #02436d;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family:"proxima";
    }
    .name{
        position: absolute;
        top: 220px;
        left: 275px;
        color: #237e2f;
        font-size: 42pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family:"english";
    }
    .month_number{
        position: absolute;
        top: 172px;
        left: 571px;
        color: #02436d;
        font-size: 28pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family:"lucida";
    }   
</style>
</head>
<body>



<body>
<div id="lol">
    <div  class="eating">10</div>
    <div  class="exercise">12</div>
    <div  class="name">Jhon Doe</div>
    <div  class="month_number">#4</div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Image can be found at http://weightlosssuccessoholics.com/pdf/30-Day-Goals-Certificate.jpg

And my pdf generator code is :

```
<?php

require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
 ob_start();

require("pdf.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();




$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->set_paper(array(0,0,629.00,410.00),'portrait');
$dompdf->render();



$dompdf->stream();
?>
```

Anyone is running into the same problem? Its looks like a ramdom error and i cant figure out the reason. Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "sharp"? could you give two PDFs: one when it is ok, and one when it's not.

Comment: Sharp in image edges. I dont have one sharp at the moment as i can not reproduce it. It just happens randomly, as soon as i get one i will upload it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can up the resolution using the following variable:
def("DOMPDF_DPI", 96);

in dompdf_config.inc.php

```
/**
 * Image DPI setting
 *
 * This setting determines the default DPI setting for images and fonts.  The
 * DPI may be overridden for inline images by explictly setting the
 * image's width & height style attributes (i.e. if the image's native
 * width is 600 pixels and you specify the image's width as 72 points,
 * the image will have a DPI of 600 in the rendered PDF.  The DPI of
 * background images can not be overridden and is controlled entirely
 * via this parameter.
 *
 * For the purposes of DOMPDF, pixels per inch (PPI) = dots per inch (DPI).
 * If a size in html is given as px (or without unit as image size),
 * this tells the corresponding size in pt.
 * This adjusts the relative sizes to be similar to the rendering of the
 * html page in a reference browser.
 *
 * In pdf, always 1 pt = 1/72 inch
 *
 * Rendering resolution of various browsers in px per inch:
 * Windows Firefox and Internet Explorer:
 *   SystemControl->Display properties->FontResolution: Default:96, largefonts:120, custom:?
 * Linux Firefox:
 *   about:config *resolution: Default:96
 *   (xorg screen dimension in mm and Desktop font dpi settings are ignored)
 *
 * Take care about extra font/image zoom factor of browser.
 *
 * In images, <img> size in pixel attribute, img css style, are overriding
 * the real image dimension in px for rendering.
 */
```